# auto incrementing id in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

How to auto increment an id in SQL Server whenever a new row is inserted in the table?
This id is primary key of the table.

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?t=41676 ?

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for [IDENTITY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933196(SQL.80).aspx).

e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable
(
ID INTEGER IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
FieldA VARCHAR(10)
)
```

The ID field will auto increment, starting at 1 and increasing by one each time.

Answer (score 0):

And to return the id in your code lookup scope_identity() and the OUTPUT clause. De not use @@identity as it can return the wrong value if triggers are put on the table, therefore it is not safe to use if you value data integrity.